# "...will be running NBA..."

Tags: grammar

I'm trying to understand the meanings of 'will' with a lexical verb in present continuous, can we use 'will run NBA...' instead? Is it still the same meanings?

For example:

> They may not be household names yet, but it's a good bet many of these people will be running NBA teams soon.

VS

> They may not be household names yet, but it's a good bet many of these people will run NBA teams soon.

Source:
https://www.sbnation.com/2014/10/1/6877405/nba-general-manager-candidates-troy-weaver-okc-thunder

Comment: In your *exact* example we can't really say there's any difference. But consider *Jack and Jill really like each other, so it's a safe bet they will **have / be having** sex soon*. Arguably the "Simple Future" there more strongly implies they might have only a *single* sexual encounter, whereas "Future Continuous" tends to imply they'll be in an ***ongoing*** sexual relationship. But you could also say that the stylistic choice of using the continuous in such contexts puts greater emphasis on the projected ongoing future state of affairs, as opposed to the specific action of taking over a team

Answer (score 1):

*Running a team* (acting as its manager) is an ongoing situation, not a single action. The article predicts that certain people will become managers of basketball teams in the near future.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! when you are saying `an ongoing situation`, does it mean that  we should use `will be running` if those people are currently running the NBA teams already? and use `will run` if those people are currently NOT running a NBA team?

Comment: Compare Colin's answer and FumbleFingers' comment. _Will be running_ does **not** mean that they are running it now. It means that, in the near future, they _will be_ managers of teams. As _running a team_ is ongoing, _will run_ is not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

As usual with aspectual expressions in English, both forms are possible, and the difference is not in the objective meaning, but in how the writer is inviting the reader to view the events or circumstances.

*Will be running* invites readers to place themselves mentally in some future time when the people will be in process of running the teams. *Will run* makes the same objective claim, but does not set any temporal focus.